# Drooping Aglaonema Pictum Tricolour! Need help!

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, indoors, chinese-evergreen

[image]

[image]

I've recently rescued 5 Pictum Tricolour at an affordable price from an old lady at the market 4 days ago. They've received two watering so far and have not perked up yet.

I've chopped up 2 of them because of stem and root damage and the other 3 still seem to be alive.

What I couldn't troubleshoot is how the leaves are all droopy. They are still firm but the structure of the leaves are still flaccid. There were some lower yellow leaves which I cut off but I'm afraid that the remaining leaves will soon turn yellow as well. I got them in regular potting mix which I planted with very well draining mix and a layer of sphagnum moss on the top layer.

Please let me know how to save them! <3

Comment: Hello Wlki.  Where are you located?  Is it winter or summer?  Do I understand you correctly, in the 4 days you have owned them you have watered them twice??  Sounds like a lot.   Do you check the soil before you water to see if it is still wet?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming a few things

They look like cuttings that have not yet fully established roots 
Hence the sphagnum moss is still in the pots.

For now you will need to give them a humidity dome as they need to stay hydrated with out roots.

Dont be afraid to take one out of the pot to have a look at the roots.
If the growing medium falls off the stem, as its ment to , then you will know it needs to grow roots.

If you dont need to change the growing medium, then you can give them a "tug test" to check if it has started to establish roots

Also you need to remember that sphagnum moss alone is perfect for rooting but requires fertiliser as it cannot feed the plant like soil.

Change the growing medium to a more subtle one like decent potting soil with good drainage.

This plant would thrive in rich potting soil,  but it can survive with low amounts of fertiliser in the soil.

Also no full sun as it is happy near a window indoors

Comment: Also when you change the medium reuse some of the sphagnum moss as it will aid in drainage (this plant does not like to keep its feet wet) and make sure you keep them in a humidity dome or bag.